# How to fix "certificate verify failed (Twitter::Error)"

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth

I'm using the [MicroBlogger tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/microblogger.html) to make a tweet bot.

I got near the end of the "I1: Posting Tweets" section. My program looks like this:

```
require 'jumpstart_auth'

class MicroBlogger
  attr_reader :client

  def initialize
    puts "Initializing MicroBlogger"
    @client = JumpstartAuth.twitter
  end

  def tweet(message)
    @client.update(message)
  end
end

blogger = MicroBlogger.new
blogger.tweet("MicroBlogger Initialized")
```

The first time I ran it, Twitter's authorization page popped up in my browser with the authorization pin. I entered the pin and my Twitter account was locked. I had two of these auth tabs open so perhaps I copy/pasted the wrong one.

After unlocking my account, I now get the following error when I run the program without being taken to the authorization page. I tried signing out of Twitter and signing in with a new account, but this makes no difference.

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\projects\microblogger>ruby micro_blogger.rb
Initializing MicroBlogger
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/reset/request.rb:37:in 'rescue in perform': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (twitter::Error)
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/request.rb:32:in 'perform'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:50:in 'perform_request'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:72:in 'perform_request_with_object'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:64:in 'perform_post_with_object'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/tweets.rb:158:in 'update!'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/twitter-5.16.0/lib/twitter/rest/tweets.rb:128:in 'update'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/jumpstart_auth-0.6.0/lib/jumpstart_auth/twitter_client.rb:33:in 'update'
from micro_blogger.rb:12:in 'tweet'
from micro_blogger.rb:17:in '<main>'
```

I feel like this is something to do with the jumpstart-auth gem and it thinking I don't need to request authorization again, but I don't know how it works.

I went back through the steps in the tutorial again. I got to this point:

> The first time this is run it’ll use the Launchy gem to pop open your web browser and ask for permission to use your account.

And it didn't pop open. Not sure if that's helpful but thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed".

It simply states the SSL certificate is invalid.

Maybe it has something to do with the v3 version since its defined as unsafe last year and is disabled on most OS's.

Comment: It's just strange that it did actually work the first time.